# Sending Mail: Authentication Failure

Tags: java, android, email

I am trying to send an email from an app and I use the following code:

```
private static final String username = "sth@gmail.com";
private static final String password = "pass";


private void sendMail(String email, String subject, String messageBody) {
        Session session = createSessionObject();

        try {
            Message message = createMessage(email, subject, messageBody, session);
            new SendMailTask().execute(message);
        } catch (AddressException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private Message createMessage(String email, String subject, String messageBody, Session session) throws MessagingException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
        Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("sth@gmail.com"));
        message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(email, email));
        message.setSubject(subject);
        message.setText(messageBody);
        return message;
    }

    private Session createSessionObject() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        properties.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
        properties.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");

        return Session.getInstance(properties, new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
            }
        });
    }

    private class SendMailTask extends AsyncTask<Message, Void, Void> {
        private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(SendQuestion.this, "Please wait", "Sending mail", true, false);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Message... messages) {
            try {
                Transport.send(messages[0]);
            } catch (MessagingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Eclipse throws javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException. When I first tried to send a mail, my gmail account received a mail from Google concerning security and that they blocked the mail. Then I activate at /lesssecureapps that I want to allow less secure apps. But this did not fix it. Is it something wrong with my code or there is a gmail issue?

PS: I have added all the necessary .jar and included Internet access to manifest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turned out, it was a problem with the server of google. I contact with the support and they fixed it. The code above works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try Doing this :

```
public static int Email(String fromemail, String toemail, String cc,
            String bcc, String Subject, String Body, String Attachment) {
        final String fromEmail = fromemail;// "user@gmail.com"; //requires
        // valid gmail id
        // final String password = Password; // correct password for gmail id
        final String toEmail = toemail;// "user2@ymail.com"; // can be any
        // email id

        MailSSLSocketFactory sf = null;
        try {
            sf = new MailSSLSocketFactory();
        } catch (GeneralSecurityException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        sf.setTrustAllHosts(true);

        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com"); // SMTP Host
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465"); // SSL Port
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class",
                "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory"); // SSL Factory Class
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true"); // Enabling SMTP Authentication
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465"); // SMTP Port

        Authenticator auth = new Authenticator() {
            // override the getPasswordAuthentication method
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication(fromEmail, Password);
            }
        };

        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, auth);

        int i;
        i = sendEmail(session, toEmail, Subject, Body);
        return i;

    }
```

this is the send function :

```
public static void sendEmail(Session session, String toEmail,
            String subject, String body) {
        try {
            MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);
            // set message headers
            msg.addHeader("Content-type", "text/HTML; charset=UTF-8");
            msg.addHeader("format", "flowed");
            msg.addHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "8bit");

            msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress("no_reply@journaldev.com",
                    "Operation Department Email"));

            msg.setReplyTo(InternetAddress.parse("no_reply@journaldev.com",
                    false));

            msg.setSubject(subject, "UTF-8");

            msg.setText(body, "UTF-8");

            msg.setSentDate(new Date());

            msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                    InternetAddress.parse(toEmail, false));
            Transport.send(msg);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 2 things:
1)i = sendEmail(session, toEmail, Subject, Body); sendEmail is void so this is error
2)For MailSSLSocketFactory should I make new class?